# Files deleted from Internal/External SD return with a size of 0 bytes

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, downloading, file-management

I am running the Resurrection Remix ROM on my i9300, I don't know what could've caused this. Every time I save files to my SD card, external or internal, for instance when I download a file from the internet and have it saved to my sdCard in storage/sdcard0/Downloads and I decide to delete that file, the file deletes fine but after a while, I check that same path and find out the files  are back with a size of 0 bytes.

After studying how the issue has been occurring, I noticed it happens with only files I download and not files I copy from my PC to the phone.

**I have tried:**

1. Deleting the files from recovery with the aroma file manager.
2. Clean install of my ROM to an updated version
3. Changing ownership of these files then deleting them from the command line via the terminal emulator app.
4. Formatting my internal and external sd storage from recovery.
5. Connecting my phone to my PC and deleting the files from there.

Here's a screenshot of how things have been going down:

[image]